# Combine channels in ImageJ Jython?

Tags: python, jython, imagej

I have two channels from an image stack which I've split like so:

```
red_c, green_c = ChannelSplitter.split(imp)
```

And now I want to combine them horizontally:

```
combined_img = StackCombiner.combineHorizontally(green_c, red_c)
```

This throws an error that says 3 arguments were expected, but only 2 provided. But from the documentation it says `combineHorizontally(ImageStack stack1, ImageStack stack2)`

Why is this not working?

---

**EDIT**: solved it. Turns out the correct way of writing it is

```
combined = StackCombiner().combineHorizontally(grn_stack, red_stack)
```

Why this needs an extra `()` but ChannelSplitter doesn't is a mystery to me. They're both imported from `ij.plugin`. Can somebody shed light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> solved it.

Glad that you found it. For the future, questions like this one are still a good fit for the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/) (where you seem to have an [account](http://forum.imagej.net/u/komodovaran) as well), particularly when you're asking about specifics of the ImageJ API.

> Why this needs an extra () but ChannelSplitter doesn't is a mystery to me.

ImageJ is a Java application, and in your Jython script you're actually calling the [Java API of `StackCombiner`](http://javadoc.scijava.org/ImageJ1/ij/plugin/StackCombiner.html). The call

```
StackCombiner.combineHorizontally(green_c, red_c)
```

would work if `combineHorizontally` was a `static` method of `StackCombiner`, but as it isn't, it needs a new `StackCombiner` object being instantiated first.

In **Java**, you'd have to write:

```java
new StackCombiner().combineHorizontally(a,b)
```

In **Python**, you don't need a `new` keyword, but you still need to use the [constructor](http://javadoc.scijava.org/ImageJ1/ij/plugin/StackCombiner.html#StackCombiner()):

```
StackCombiner().combineHorizontally(a,b)
```

---

In contrast, the [`ChannelSplitter.split(ImagePlus)` method](http://javadoc.scijava.org/ImageJ1/ij/plugin/ChannelSplitter.html#split(ij.ImagePlus)) is `static`, so you can use it without instantiating an object.